# How to convert negative numbers and numbers with decimal point , in binary, hexadecimal, octal, decimal

Tags: java, converters

I would like to make a converter decimal, binary, hexadecimal, octal. This is what I managed to do for now, using java libraries

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class convertitore {

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String binario = null; 
String ottale = null;
int decimale = 0, sel;
String esa = null;

System.out.println("Choose the type of number to convert: ");
System.out.println("Enter 1 for decimal");
System.out.println("Enter 2 for binary");
System.out.println("Enter 3 for hexadecimal");
System.out.println("Enter 4 for octal");

sel = scanner.nextInt();


if (sel == 1){

System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
decimale = scanner.nextInt();

esa = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(decimale);
binario = java.lang.Integer.toBinaryString(decimale);
ottale = java.lang.Integer.toOctalString(decimale); 
System.out.println("The decimal number entered is: " + decimale);
System.out.println("The hexadecimal number entered is: " + esa);
System.out.println("The binary number entered is: " + binario);
System.out.println("The octal number entered is: " + ottale);

}

if (sel == 2){

System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
binario = scanner.next();

decimale = Integer.parseInt(binario.toString(),2);
esa = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(decimale);
ottale = java.lang.Integer.toOctalString(decimale); 
System.out.println("The binary number entered is: " + binario);
System.out.println("The hexadecimal number entered is:  " + esa);
System.out.println("The decimal number entered is:  " + decimale);
System.out.println("The octal number entered is:  " + ottale);

}

if (sel == 3){

System.out.println("Inserisci un numero binario: ");
esa = scanner.next();

decimale = Integer.parseInt(esa.toString(),16);
binario = java.lang.Integer.toBinaryString(decimale);
ottale = java.lang.Integer.toOctalString(decimale); 
System.out.println("Il numero esadecimale inserito è: " + esa);
System.out.println("Il numero inserito in binario è: " + binario);
System.out.println("Il numero inserito in decimale è: " + decimale);
System.out.println("Il numero inserito in ottale è: " + ottale);

}

if (sel == 4){

System.out.println("Inserisci un numero binario: ");
ottale = scanner.next();

decimale = Integer.parseInt(ottale.toString(),8);
esa = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(decimale);
binario = java.lang.Integer.toOctalString(decimale);

System.out.println("Il numero ottale inserito è: " + ottale);
System.out.println("Il numero inserito in esacemale è: " + esa);
    System.out.println("Il numero inserito in decimale è: " + decimale);
    System.out.println("Il numero inserito in binario è: " + binario);  
}   
}
}
```

But I would like to improve the conversion, with numbers with the decimal point and negative numbers, you would have any advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert numbers with decimal points, you can use the class [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) and its methods, `toHexString` and `doubleToLongBits`.